# SQL Server Resize Data type from Integer to Tiny Int

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with about 10 Million records.

Two of those columns are of data type Integer.

But those two columns only store values from 1 to 124 only.

The values in those column will never exceed the values of 150.

So I need to change those values to "Tiny Int" data type.

How can I do this safely, and by doing this will I be able to recovery space.

Please kindly provide me with script and Graphical User Interface methods also please.

Comment: why have you added tag mysql and sql-server both, please remove one

Comment: Dear Ashu, I have removed the mysql tag. Thank you for answering my question. But I also need to know that if this would recover a lot of space on the hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sqlserver you can do it like this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName smallint
```

Comment: does this helped you

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I also need to know that if this would recover a lot of space on the hard drive

Comment: yes now it will take less space on hard drive and recover lot of space, please mark it as answer if you find this is a correct answer you were looking for